# Criar extensão para manipular DOM de outras páginas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de manipular o DOM de outra página com a minha extensão.

Ex: eu abro o popup da extensão e lá tem um botão, e nesse botão chamo uma função JavaScript:

```
var n1 = document.getElementById("div1").value;
var n2 = document.getElementById("div2").value;

return n1+n2;
```

Só que quando eu acesso o DOM da popup, a necessidade é acessar o DOM da página aberta, e retornar a soma dos valores da página aberta para o DOM do popup.

**Manifest**

```js
{
  "name": "Teste",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Teste.",
   "browser_action":{
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "background.html"
   },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
  
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{width:425px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="Captura()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("div").length);
```

Fazendo alguns teste tive o resultado. Toda Vez que eu atualizo a página do google, minha extensão mostra a quantidade de div do mesmo. a minha Duvida  é, 
é possível acionar esse evento somente quando eu clicar no botão no popup.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que não dá para acessar diretamente, entretanto você pode executar uma função no escopo da página usando [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) e depois coletar o resultado usando [comunicação através do *shared DOM*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication).

Exemplo de extensão escutando por evento `message`:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  if (event.source != window)
    return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
    console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
    port.postMessage(event.data.text);
  }
}, false);
```

Exemplo de script injetado enviando uma mensagem ao clicar num botão da página:

```
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
  window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
}, false);
```